# Removing characters from font

Tags: ios, uikit, uifont, textkit, uifontdescriptor

As far as I can tell from [this WWDC doc](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2r3j3v6uiaeewrp/Screenshot%202014-12-23%2011.50.50.png?dl=0), my code should work, but it doesn't:

```
NSString *fontName = [@"MaisonNeue-" stringByAppendingString:@"Light"];
UIFont *originalFont = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
UIFontDescriptor *originalDescriptor = [originalFont fontDescriptor];

NSMutableCharacterSet *cset = [[originalDescriptor objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorCharacterSetAttribute] mutableCopy];
[cset formIntersectionWithCharacterSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];

NSDictionary *newAttributes = @{UIFontDescriptorCharacterSetAttribute: cset};

UIFontDescriptor *monospaceDescriptor = [originalDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:newAttributes];
UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:monospaceDescriptor size:0.0];
```

What's wrong? The newly created font still contains the characters I specifically removed:

```
(lldb) p [cset characterIsMember:'2']
(bool) $0 = false
(lldb) po [(NSCharacterSet *)[(id)monospaceDescriptor objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorCharacterSetAttribute] characterIsMember:'2']
false
(lldb) po [(NSCharacterSet *)[[newFont fontDescriptor] objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorCharacterSetAttribute] characterIsMember:'2']
true
```

Comment: Hm... `[(NSCharacterSet *)[[newFont fontDescriptor] objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorCharacterSetAttribute] characterIsMember:'2']` returns false for me. But it also looks as if even if the characters are removed from the font, they're replaced by characters from another font while typing...

Comment: @LyndseyScott Are you testing with `[UIFont systemFont..]`? I think that gave different results than a custom font created with `[UIFont fontWithName:...]`. Also, it is not being replaced with characters from another font, since if it did, I'd be getting the result I want. The whole idea is that the font I am using has really bad looking digits, so I to display digits from another font.

Comment: No, I'm using the Chalkduster font so I can see a clear difference.

Comment: Could you include your lines initializing the font and descriptor? And the line setting your textfield/view font?

Comment: OK, so you've imported MaisonNeue-Light I presume and MCFont's a custom UIFont class of some sort? What happens if you replace "MCFont" with "UIFont"? Does it work then?

Comment: Also perhaps you should set the font size in this line: `[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:monospaceDescriptor size:0.0];` to something other than 0 for safe measure.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Sorry, `MCFont` is a `UIFont` #define, since it is #defined as `NSFont` for Mac. Forgot to update it.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I changed the size... Then, started testing other fonts, as I was surprised it worked for you, and it worked for system custom fonts, but not my imported fonts.